# TFS Workflows 2012, loading Visual Studio 2013 DLL

Tags: tfsbuild, workflow-foundation-4, load-testing

I am using TFS workflows 2012 to automate my build system. I am facing difficulty in loading one of the assembly referred by the solution:

```
**Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.LoadTest.dll**
DETAILS - Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.LoadTest, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a

The build compiles but fails with runtime error - Unable to find assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.LoadTest, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

The assembly is present in the build controller binaries folder. Also I have set the properties of this DLL in Visual Studio as, Specific Version = true.

I have tried various things till now, but somehow it still gives this error:

1. Registered the DLL in GAC: C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL
2. Dynamically tried to load this assembly:

   ```
   Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.LoadTest.dll");
   ```

But still it gives me the same error.

Is it like we cannot use VS 2013 DLLs in VS 2012 workflows? or I am doing something wrong here?

Note: If I create a sample application (exe) in Build Controller, and then from the workflow if I execute this exe, it runs absolutely fine. So this has to do something with workflows.

Comment: Fusion logging.  Search for it, do it, and you'll learn where TFS is looking for DLLs.  Also, seems weird you are referencing that :/

Answer (score 0):

Do you have VS 2013 installed on the box running the VS 2012 workflow?  If you're running a TFS 2012 agent you may need to install VS 2013 on your build server before it has those assemblies.